# Nodejs request-promise combining json api data from 2 links?

Tags: node.js, json, request, request-promise

```
const express = require('express');
const app     = express();
const path    = require('path');
const config  = require('./config.json');
const moment = require('moment');

const request = require('request-promise');

url = 'https://ne.api.site',
url2 = 'https://n2.api.site',


app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

async function getApi(){
  return request({
        url : url,
        url2 : url2
    });

}


/* Routes */
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  let api = await getApi();
  let json = await JSON.parse(api);
  res.render('home', { api: json, moment: require('moment')});
});


app.listen(4800, () => console.log('Express listening on port 4800'));
```

I am trying to combine the 2 json api urls(the data from them), and cant seem to figure out what to do. Do I need to create an array? If so how? So I am trying to combine the data from different urls(because of different regions) all onto one main page that can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely not use `request-promise` anymore since the request-module, on which request-promise depends, has been [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). Now, to answer your question.. assuming you're using [superagent](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagen) as a http request-module, you could do:

```
const request = require('superagent');
const moment = require('moment');

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  // responses will be an array of the resolved responses of the two calls
  const responses = await getApi();           
  res.render('home', { api: responses, moment: moment() });
});

function requestApis() {
 return Promise.all([request.get(url),request.get(url2)]);
}
```

Comment: @OP: any feedback?